# How do you get vertex buffer of mesh?

Tags: c++, directx

How to get vertex information of mesh?

Comment: Er, what graphics framework? OpenGL? D3D? RamilolGraphiX?

Comment: You need to provide a lot more information here if you want any useful answers....

Comment: I swear i thought i put directx

Comment: C++ or C? (Tangential, sure, but I hope you don't think they're the same!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean from an ID3DXMesh then its just a matter of calling [GetVertexBuffer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb205747%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [GetIndexBuffer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb205742%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).  To get additional information, such as the vertex structure, you can call [GetDescription](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb205739%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).  Finally to get the information about how the mesh should be rendered (such as which verts use the same material) the information can be obtained by calling [GetAttributeTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb205738%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).  You do, though, need to know which attribute id maps to which texture.